# Kunneth formula: tensor product of complexes commutes with homology, over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $C, D$ two complexes of $k$ modules and $C \otimes D$ the tensor product of $C$ and $D$ over $k$.
($(C \otimes D)^n = \oplus (C^p \otimes D^q)$ and its coboundary is given by $c \otimes d \mapsto \delta c \otimes d + (-1)^{-p} c \otimes \delta d $. )
Then $h^*(C\otimes D) \cong h^*(C) \otimes h^*(D)$?

I have shown that the Kunneth for two quasi-compact separated schemes over a field and quasi-coherent sheaves follows from this.

Comment: I think this result is called the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Zilber_theorem)